# Обфускация строковых констант

Tags: .net

Кто-нибудь любопытствовал на тему, как обфускаторы .net шифруют строки? Я полагал, что это делается через подмену строки-операнда инструкции ldstr на шифрованную строку и инъекции после ldstr функции-дешифровщика, но глядя на обфусцированные исходники не вижу никаких дешифровщиков. Например, babel-обфускатор превратил мою строку

```
String s = "psw" ;
```

В

```
String s = "...";
```

И ничего более

Эта функция присутствует во многих бесплатных обфускаторах

Как же распутываются такие строки в процессе выполнения?

Comment: приведенной информации недостаточно

Comment: Брайнфак? :) Это ключ, где то живёт диктонарий в той или иной реализации, по ключу добывают строку, скорей всего шифрованную..

Comment: @NewView, встречал такие примеры. Например, некоторые обфускаторы заменяют строку на вызов некой функции с аргументом в виде числа. Такой подход более менее понятен, хотя и более трудоемок, поскольку размер вызова такой функции будет занимать на 5 байт больше, а значит придётся сдвигать все ссылки ниже по коду после инъекции. А вот случай с заменой строки на заведомо нечитаемую без вызовов для меня загадка

Comment: Так там стартер встраивается, который при запуске это распутывает, по известному ему алгоритму, а потом уже грузит как сборку.

Comment: @NewView, то есть получается, что в процессе выполнения все строки уже раскированы?

Comment: По сути скорее да, или доступны в шифрованное виде, и их перед "употреблением" расшифровывают.. легче исходники этого Бабеля глянуть.. :)

Comment: Самое лучшее, это разнести значимый код по неуправляемым библиотекам, и получать данные для приложения с сервиса в сети. И не мучать себя обфуксаторами, по факту, от них больше глюков, чем пользы. После обфуксатора, надо плотно тестировать то что получилось.

Comment: @NewView так там закрытый исходный код